# Programmatically inflated layout with Kotlin Android Extensions

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvErrorTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvErrorDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I want to use [kotlin android extensions][1] outside of activity like below, it doesn't work. I ended up doing findViewById.

```
...
...
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.*
...
...
 val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_error, null, false)
    val tvErrorTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.tvErrorTitle) as TextView
    val tvErrorDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.tvErrorDesc) as TextView
    val tvErrorAction = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAction) as TextView
```

It doesn't pull the views directly from xml. How to use it in programmatically inflated layout and avoid `findViewById`?

**Note** : This question strictly belongs to [Kotlin Android Extensions][1], not the language itself.

**Edit**
I have imported both :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.*
```

But Android Studio still tries to import from R.id and doesn't recognize those two imports. Is there anything missing?
[1]: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: avoid `findViewById`? what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html see here you will get the idea

Comment: try using one of imports, like only `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.*`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the [docs you linked](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html):

> If we want to call the synthetic properties on View (useful in adapter classes), we should also import
>
> ```
> kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*.
> ```

That is, import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout.view.*` as well to load the `View` extension properties.

Then:

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(...)
view.tvErrorTitle.text = "test"
```

Comment: I have imported both now : import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_error.* But IDE isn't pulling that . Instead, it tries to import from R.id

Comment: Are you referencing the properties on the inflated `View`?

Comment: yes. I want to inflate a view and then get views inside it

Comment: that works but not understand u.u only is different in dialogFragment ? because is custom ? need import view

Comment: @nhaarman how can i inflate the view if i have an error saying : Unresolved Refferrance :R? thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It returns a view inflated:

`layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null)`

See, you can replace this `LayoutInflater.from(context)` with this `layoutInflater` when your class extend from a Context superclass

Comment: This helped me. I followed the official android tutorial on DialogFragment, to a T. I kept getting a crash with error located at four lines, repeating indefinitely, seemingly rooted at Fragment.getLayoutInflater(). This fixed it. Not sure why it's not in the tutorial. (I would make a question of my problem and this solution but SO is bs and won't let me ask anymore questions.)

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin you can try this to inflate layout inside linear layout using databinding

```
val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity).context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

 val mBindingDeno: LayoutDenominationBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.layout_denomination, null, false
        )
layout.addView(mBindingDeno.root)
```

Here layout is your LinearLayout

```
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_denomination"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />


            </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding:**

Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported. If your app uses Kotlin synthetics for view binding, use this guide to migrate to Jetpack view binding.

If your app does not already use Kotlin synthetics for view binding, see View binding for basic usage information.

Like Android Extensions, Jetpack view binding is enabled on a module by module basis. For each module that uses view binding, set the viewBinding build option to true in the module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

**Use view binding in activities**

To set up an instance of the binding class for use with an activity, perform the following steps in the activity's `onCreate()` method:

Call the static `inflate()` method included in the generated binding class. This creates an instance of the binding class for the activity to use.
Get a reference to the root view by either calling the `getRoot()` method or using Kotlin property syntax.

Pass the root view to `setContentView()` to make it the active view on the screen.

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

You can now use the instance of the binding class to reference any of the views:

```kotlin
binding.name.text = viewModel.name
binding.button.setOnClickListener { viewModel.userClicked() }
```

For more information: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities