# TextView Null after inflating parent layout

Tags: android, layout, kotlin, layout-inflater

TextView Null after inflating parent layout.
I'm running a loop which inflates a number of these layouts:

```
for(i in ticketAr?.indices!!){

    var inf1:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    var infv:View = inf1.inflate(R.layout.ticket_individual,null,false)
    infv.setId(parseInt(ticketAr[i].string("ntb_id")))
    var thetitle = infv.tck_event_title
    thetitle.setText(ticketAr[i].string("age_group_desc"))
}
```

**STACKTRACE**

```
10-25 09:30:35.839 11549-11549/com.example.xx.listview
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.xx.listview, PID: 11549
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

  at
com.example.xx.listview.Ordering_Setup$getData$1.invoke(Ordering_Setup.kt:145)
  at
com.example.xx.listview.Ordering_Setup$getData$1.invoke(Ordering_Setup.kt:29)
  at
com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:37)
  at
com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt)
  at
com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:62)
  at
com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$5$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt)
  at
com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Request$callback$1.run(Request.kt:225)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Try my answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `findViewById()` anywhere in your code. Instead of doing:

```
 var thetitle = infv.tck_event_title
```

Try this:

```
 var thetitle = infv.findViewById(R.id.tck_event_title) as TextView
```

Or the equivalent ID of that `TextView` you're trying to use.

Also, you're creating a new `LayoutInflater` on each loop. This line of code:

```
var inf1:LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

Should really be outside the loop (And can even be a `val` instead of a `var`).

**Edit:** If you were trying to use the Kotlin Android Extensions, I suggest that you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748437/4070469). You might've forgotten to import something.

Comment: What had happened is that Android Studio reverted my custom layout names to the generic Textview7/8 etc etc. The GUI was showing my custom names but the XML behind the scenes was showing the generic names. Reported it as a bug to the developer

Comment: Oh I see. So you were in fact using the Kotlin Android Extensions. Glad to know you figured it out :) (But don't forget to create the inflater outside the loop!)

Comment: Yes I was. I just started learning development a few weeks ago so I decided to start right with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Not really and answer other then the original code does work.

What had happened is that Android Studio reverted my custom layout names to the generic Textview7/8 etc etc. The GUI was showing my custom names but the XML behind the scenes was showing the generic names. Reported it as a bug to the developer